# How to do an Ajax request to parse table row column data to PHP on click of table row?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a datatable with an numeric value in the first column of the `<tr><td>` row.

I want to click on that row and parse this value to a PHP page in order to assign this number into a session.

I have below code snippet, but this isn't do the push.

`selected` is the class of the row when I click on it.

```
$(".selected td").click(function(parsegroupid) {
    var group_id = $(this).attr('data');

    $.ajax({
        url: "./includes/indexPage/assign_session.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            id: group_id
        },
        success: function(response) {
        }
    });
});
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}


$GrpID = $_POST['group_id'];

$_SESSION['grp'] = $GrpID;


ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Below is a screenshot of the row when selected.[image]

Comment: add code of your `assign_session.php` file

Comment: i have added it.

Comment: Is the ajax call being made? (Do you see it in your network tab of chrome/firefox with the correct post parameters)?

Comment: try to var_dump this like `var_dump($_POST['group_id'])` and see what result you get

Comment: @FrankerZ I can't see it in the chrome log. It looks like the click event didn't happen.

Comment: The td is added after document.ready is fired. Try binding it using on(latest Jquery) or live (older version)

Comment: "selected is the class of the row when I click on it" - does it mean this class is added to `tr` as a result of click? If yes, in the moment of first click on that row `".selected td"` selector will not work, because, when click event is triggered, that row doesn't have this class yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to check if the ajax call is made.
Based on your previous comments, it seems this is not happening.

You can try to specify the table id in your onclick event:

```
$("#table_id tbody").on( 'click', 'tr', function (){

    var group_id = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();

    $.ajax({
        url: "./includes/indexPage/assign_session.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            id: group_id
        },
        success: function(response) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is going into the right direction. Now i can see it is doing the call, but not yet parse the value.

Comment: Then you can check the value of group_id by using console.log().

Comment: @Cyber If you only need the first element, you can use the example I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

Make the change in your `assign_session.php` file your have pass the value in `id` and trying to access value of  `group_id`.

> Instead of `$_POST['group_id']` use `$_POST['id']`

change the code like below

```
<?php
ob_start();
if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}


$GrpID = $_POST['id']; // change 

$_SESSION['grp'] = $GrpID;


ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: This was a mix up in my php. I corrected it and this piece is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the ID is in the cell of the  and not as an attribute, try this:

```
var group_id = $(this).html();
```

Comment: It is the cell value indeed.

Comment: it is the first cell value. How can I determine the first column of that row? With your suggestion, it pushes the entire row as html as id.

Comment: var group_id = $(this).siblings(':first-child').html()

Comment: still giving me the entire row as html code.  `id:<td tabindex="0">58623</td><td>Test</td><td>2017-06-03</td><td class="sorting_1">2017-06-30</td><td>2</td><td>Requested</td><td><div style="text-align:center;"><span class="badge badge-success">Approved</span></div></td>`

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the row when clicked.

Comment: @Cyber You can use this: var group_id = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();

Comment: @mufax that was the missing piece. Thanks it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Go with this code.

You are posting `id` and `group_id` is your value and you added `$_POST['group_id']` instead of `$_POST['id']`.

Hope this will helps you :)

```
<?php
ob_start();
if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}


$GrpID = $_POST['id']; // Change here

$_SESSION['grp'] = $GrpID;


ob_end_flush();
?>
```